# Foor loop prints all elements, but when result is saved in pandas dataframe it returns NaN

Tags: python, json, for-loop, web-scraping

I have the following scraping script, I need to get elements inside a "items2" foor loop.
The script is printing all elements, but later on dataframe returns "name" and "tPlan" as NaN. Any idea why?

```
import requests  
import json
import csv
import sys

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


base_url = "xxxx"  
username = "xxxx"  
password = "xxxx"
toget = data

allowed_results = 50  
max_results = "maxResults=" + str(allowed_results)
tc = "/testcycles?"

result_count = -1  
start_index = 0  

df = pd.DataFrame(
  columns=['id', 'name', 'gId', 'dKey', 'tPlan'])

for eachId in toget['TPlan_ID']:
   while result_count != 0:  
      start_at = "startAt=" + str(start_index)
      url = url = f'{base_url}{eachId}{tc}&{start_at}&{max_results}'  
      response = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))  
      json_response = json.loads(response.text)
      print(json_response)
      page_info = json_response["meta"]["pageInfo"]
      start_index = page_info["startIndex"] + allowed_results  
      result_count = page_info["resultCount"]
      items2 = json_response["data"]
      print(items2)

      for item in items2:
          print (item["id"])            
          print (item["fields"]["name"])
          print (item["fields"]["gId"])
          print (item["fields"]["dKey"])
          print (item["fields"]["tPlan"])
        
          temporary_df = pd.DataFrame([item], columns=['id', 'name', 'gId', 'dKey', 'tPlan'])
          df = df.append(temporary_df, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Could you please add the ```items2``` value in your question. Not the whole list but just a few items would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TLDR

Use this for loop.

```py
for item in items2:
    df = df.append({'id': item['id'], **item['fields']}, ignore_index=True)
```

### Explanation

I am making this assumption that the `items2` would look something like this.

```py
items2 = [
    { 'id': 0, 'fields': {'name': 'prop1', 'gId': 100, 'dKey': 'key1', 'tPlan': 'plan1'}},
    { 'id': 1, 'fields': {'name': 'prop2', 'gId': 200, 'dKey': 'key2', 'tPlan': 'plan2'}},
    { 'id': 2, 'fields': {'name': 'prop3', 'gId': 300, 'dKey': 'key3', 'tPlan': 'plan3'}},
]
```

You can't create your intended data frame since the structure of `item` is like this.

```py
{'id': 2, 'fields': {'name': 'prop3', 'gId': 300, 'dKey': 'key3', 'tPlan': 'plan3'}}
```

which results in `temporary_df` filled with NaN.

```
   id name  gId dKey tPlan fields
0   0  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   key1
1   0  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN    100
2   0  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  prop1
3   0  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  plan1
4   1  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   key2
5   1  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN    200
6   1  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  prop2
7   1  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  plan2
8   2  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   key3
9   2  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN    300
10  2  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  prop3
11  2  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  plan3
```

What you would need to pass as argument to pd.DataFrame is a dict structure like

```py
{'id': 2, 'name': 'prop3', 'gId': 300, 'dKey': 'key3', 'tPlan': 'plan3'}
```

Notic the missing `fields` dict here, all the key value pair from `fields` are added to `item`. Using this altered dict would result in  `temporary_df` like

```
  id   name  gId  dKey  tPlan
0  0  prop1  100  key1  plan1
1  1  prop2  200  key2  plan2
2  2  prop3  300  key3  plan3
```

To make this change in item structure you should do this

```py
new_item = {'id': item['id']}
for key, value in item['fields'].items():
    new_item[key] = value
```

But you can write this concisely by using the [unpacking operator](https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/) `**`

```py
new_item = {'id': item['id'], **item['fields']}
```

Now we can use pass `new_item` as argument to `pd.DataFrame`.

```py
temp_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'id': item['id'], **item['fields']}, index=(i,)) # i here is the row index of the DataFrame
```

After making these changes your for loop should look something like this

```py
for i, item in enumerate(items2):
    new_item = {'id': item['id'], **item['fields']}
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(new_item, index=(i,))
    df = df.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)
```

We can make this a bit more concise by directly passing the `new_item` to `pd.DataFrame.append`

Thus in the end this code should work.

```py
for item in items2:
    new_item = {'id': item['id'], **item['fields']}
    df = df.append(new_item, ignore_index=True)
```